# Cardview de bem-vindo

Tags: android

Tenho um cardview de bem vindo. Gostaria de depois da primeira visualização o usuário pressionasse o botão de Ok, entendi e o card saisse e não aparece mais. [image: Cardview de bem vindo]

Já coloquei no XML o onClick:

```
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            style="@style/Material_Card_View"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius"
            card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/card_elevation">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/cardbemvindo">

                <include layout="@layout/headline_16dp" />

                <include layout="@layout/supporting_text_24dp" />

                <include layout="@layout/divider" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ok_button"
                    style="@style/Material_Action"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_check"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/big_padding"
                    android:text="@string/card_ok"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:onClick="clickOK"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

facin cara... salva um valor(1 e 0) como se fosse um boleano no sheredPreferences e no oncreate voce adiciona ele caso o valor seja 0 , caso seja um voce desenha o resto da tela normal.

pra isso voce tem que por os xmls separados e add ele quando for falso(quando for 0 no sheredpreference) e config pra quando ele clicar no botao voce pode chamar um metodo na classe do oncreate dele(na activity que ele estiver) e, isso e importante kkkkk,quando ele clicar voce poe pra 1 pra nao aparecer mais.

Comment: Apesar das dicas de usarem o sheredPreferences serem ótimas, ainda prefiro e acho mais simples usar o banco local (SQLite)

Comment: o problema em usar o sqlite e que ficaria desnesserario, e gastaria tempo fazendo isso, e perderia eficiencia, mais e uma opcao, e fica a gosto...

Answer (score 0):

Como dito, você pode salvar este estado no `SharedPreferences`:

Segue um exemplo:

```
    public static final String IS_SHOW = "IS_SHOW";
    public static final String PREFERENCES = "PREFERENCES";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
   TextView.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.ok_button)).setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setIsShow(true, getApplicationContext());
            }
        });

        boolean isShow = getIsShow(getApplicationContext());

        cardView.setVisibility(isShow ? View.GONE : View.GONE);

   }


    public boolean getIsShow(final Context mContext){
        //Cria uma instancia do SharedPreferences
        final SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return prefs.getBoolean(IS_SHOW, false);
    }


    /**
     * Grava as informações do objeto em um SharedPreferences.
     * @param mContext
     */
    public void setIsShow(boolean isShow, final Context mContext){
        //Cria uma instancia do SharedPreferences
        SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // Criamos um instancia do editor, para salvamos os dados
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        // para que sempre atualize, passamos o valor do Sistema.
        editor.putBoolean(IS_SHOW, isShow)
        // Para que as informações sejam atualizadas
        editor.apply();
    }
```

Comment: Eai Thiago. Fiz pelo seu exemplo que você me dize mas está dando um erro quando executo.

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
No meu cardview estou trabalhando com includes, então dei o id parao relatiive. Editei a minha pergunta e coloquei o código lá. Dá uma conferida lá, por favor.

Comment: Então o  **ok_button** é um **TextView** e não um **Button** ! Tente assim: **TextView.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.ok_button)).setOnClickListener**

Comment: Conseguiu? Coloca ai se tiver dúvida! estamos aqui pra ajudar!

Comment: Consegui colocar. Mas ainda dá o mesmo erro. =(. Ai fiz assim: TextView.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.cardView)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { ....

Comment: Então! você tenque respeitar o que tá declarado no no seu XML

Comment: Então mano, ai que tá. Sou meio leigo no Java ainda. Só copiei o teu código e coloquei lá. Sei que nem de longe é um método para aprender. É que to com prazo apertado pra entregar meu app. =( Mas valeu ai pela ajuda mano. Vou da mais uma estudada por aqui.

Comment: O elemento que tem o id **cardView** é um **CardView** então você terá de fazer o cast para um **CardView** . o Elemento **ok_button**  é um **TextView** então o cast é para **TextView** ! Vou corrigir minha resposta !

Comment: Ta blz então mano. Se tu corrigir vou pegar a tua resposta e jogar lá. Caso der algum erro vou procurar por aqui. Obrigado pela força cara.

Comment: Hahaha! Sugiro prestar atenção nos erros! Eles mostram o que estamos fazendo de errado!  Boa sorte aí !

Comment: Blz cara. Sugestão anotada. Obrigado pelo ajuda. Abs.